# Amazon S3 Read Multiple .gz Files with header

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-kinesis

I uploaded a .csv file (approximately 900,000 rows) to S3 by using Kinesis Firehose with .gz format. (I had to use it). After that I tried to read it in a Spark Application like that:

```
val path = "s3a://my-bucket/data-from-stream/2020/03/*/*/*"
var df = spark.read
  .option("sep", ",")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .csv(path = path)
```

In a bucket, there is no any other file except .gz files sent by Kinesis Firehose. 
The problem is that the application cannot find the header and replaces any line with the header.
Like that:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|7          |harry      |46         |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|          2|       john|         22|
|          5|       mary|         37|
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

It supposed to be:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|id         |name       |age        |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|          2|       john|         22|
|          5|       mary|         37|
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: post any csv sample of your gz. it seems that there is no header at all.

Comment: I am absolutely sure that there is a header in the csv file. 
First 5 row:

id,member,amount,new_amount,loan,term,int_rate \n
1077501,1296599,5000,5000,4975,3 months,10.65 \n
1077430,1314167,2500,2500,2500, 24 months,15.27 \n
1077175,1313524,2400,2400,2400,36 months,15.96 \n
1076863,1277178,10000,10000,10000,18 months,13.49 \n

Comment: Your .gz file means *.csv.gz right?

Comment: @Lamanus no because I am using Kinesis Firehose and it writes records as .gz file. Like I said I have to use Kinesis Firehose and I don't know if there is a way to make it writes as .csv.gz. When I read .gz files with sc.textFile() it reads the lines in order. However when I use spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("csvfile.csv") it does not work.

Comment: 1. do know that   .option("inferSchema", "true") means "read the entire file once just to infer the schema" before doing any useful work. I'd recommend you define the s